# how proof that: $P\left( {\max \left( {{a_i}} \right) < b} \right) = P\left( {\bigcap\limits_i ({{a_i} < b)} } \right)$

Tags: probability, statistics

How proof, using formal mathematics theory, that if $a_i$ are independent and identically distributed random variables: $$P\left( {\max \left( {{a_i}} \right) < b} \right) = P\left( {\bigcap\limits_i ({{a_i} < b)} } \right)$$

Intuitively and logically this can be considered obvious and easy:
$$max \space {{a_i}} < b == a_1 <b \space \Lambda\space  a_2 <b \space \Lambda \space etc\space    \Lambda \space a_n < b$$

The issue is to proof mathematically, since for example:
$$P\left( {\max \left( {{a_i}} \right) > b} \right) \neq P\left( {\bigcap\limits_i ({{a_i} > b)} } \right)$$

Colleagues and i found this issue, when applying the Hoeffding Inequality to multiple random variables, in problem 1.7 b) of Professor Yaser Abu-Moustafa lectures. It may look that it is a very simple proof, but most tutorials assume this and i didn't found in google or stack exchange any demonstration. Again consider reply using formal mathematics accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Could you show how the second statement that you wrote is an issue for the proof?

Comment: What do you mean when you write the intersection of a family of R.V.'s?

Comment: It is true to say $P({\min \left( a_i \right) > b})  = P(\forall i: ({a_i > b) }) $

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov - I would assume $(a_i <b)$ is supposed to be an event and so their intersection is the event they all occur

Answer (score 1):

It's because the maximum of a finite set of numbers is less than $b$ if and only if *all* of the numbers are less than $b$. For example, the maximum of $a_1$ and $a_2$ is less than $1.5$ if and only if $a_1<1.5$ and $a_2<1.5$.

Comment: The intuitionis easier and almost straightforward without adding probabilities.  It's just that usually it's good to visualize the problems in terms of the event space, and it would require a lot of combinatorics to itemize LHS and RHS, and then demonstrate they are equal. Basically if A<=>B then P(A)=P(B), so if no one else is willing to do it i will consider this answer correct (although was hoping for someone to explore the combinatorics explanation, both are known to work, but the former is not so obvious and more laborious). Although know both, i thank all participants in here cheers.